# How to install Grub inside windows 7

Tags: windows, linux, grub

I want to install grub inside windows 7.
I don't want to partition anything neither I want to remove Windows Boot Loader (BCD).
I simply want to Use Grub from windows 7 boot menu.
I want to do this so for frugal install of linux distros such as puppy, slitaz, etc. 
I have used WinGrub on Windows XP and it worked fine. But I don't think that will work on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://iruel430.blogspot.com/2010/04/wingrub-not-working-at-windows-7.html) is a page the describes how to do something like that.